# CasperJS failing on click event and assertEquals with CoffeeScript

Tags: unit-testing, coffeescript, playframework-2.0, casperjs

I have some CoffeeScript files that I'm trying to test with CasperJS in the Play! Framework w/ Java.  A couple different tests are failing and I'm unable to figure out why.  The first kind of test is handling a `click` event.  We're using:

```
casper.start(casper.uri("/starting/url"))
casper.then ->
  casper.click "#start-hsa-app-button"
```

And that gives me the error:

```
CasperError: Cannot dispatch click event on nonexistent selector: #start-hsa-app-button
```

The link with `id` `#start-hsa-app-button` definitely DOES exist.

The second error is using `assertEquals`.  The second step after the step above is:

```
casper.then ->
  @test.comment "US / non-US address switching"
  @assertNotVisible  "#address3"
  @assertVisible "#city"
  @assertVisible "#state"
  @assertVisible "#zip"
  @test.comment "click #nonUsAddress on"
  @click "#nonUsAddress"
  @assertVisible "#address3"
  @assertNotVisible "#city"
  @assertNotVisible "#state"
  @assertNotVisible "#zip"
  @test.comment "click #nonUsAddress off"
  @click "#nonUsAddress"
```

Which returns `null` for all asserts:

```
# US / non-US address switching
FAIL #address3 not visible
#    type: assertEquals
#    subject: null
#    expected: false
FAIL #city visible
#    type: assertEquals
#    subject: null
#    expected: true
FAIL #state visible
#    type: assertEquals
#    subject: null
#    expected: true
FAIL #zip visible
#    type: assertEquals
#    subject: null
#    expected: true
# click #nonUsAddress on
FAIL #coverageType_I not checked
#    type: assertEquals
#    subject: null
#    expected: false
FAIL #coverageGroupName not visible
#    type: assertEquals
#    subject: null
#    expected: false
FAIL #coverageGroupNumber not visible
#    type: assertEquals
#    subject: null
#    expected: false
```

So to me it seems like the `asserts` are getting `null` returned instead of the expected values.  Are there any errors with my CoffeeScript?  I'm new to using it so I can't say I'm certain that I'm doing things correctly.  Or is it some other interaction between Play!, CasperJS and CoffeeScript?

Comment: Verbose mode in CasperJS might help find the problem. See http://casperjs.org/debugging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that while I was working on this another dev was working on the tests I was trying to use.  Once he finished everything ended up working.  *Face-Palm*